# It is not work "Paste Feature" in my code. by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code by using Excel VBA.
It seems that it can be copied, but it cannot be copied to the new sheet of the newly created file. Continue to a specific row " ' Paste the copied row to the new sheet
There is an error in newSheet.Rows(newSheet.Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues", but I can't fix it. Is there anyone who can solve it?

The purpose of the code is:
If the word haynes is entered in column f of Excel files collected in a folder, the entire row must be copied and rearranged.

```
Sub CopyRowsWithHaynes()

' Create a new workbook to store the copied data
Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

' Create a new sheet in the new workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = newWorkbook.Sheets.Add

' Set the name of the new sheet
newSheet.Name = "Haynes Rows"

' Define the folder to search for Excel files
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = "C:\Excel Files"

' Get a list of all Excel files in the folder
Dim file As String
file = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xl*")

' Loop through each file in the folder
Do While file <> ""

  ' Open the current Excel file
  Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
  Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & file)

  ' Loop through each sheet in the workbook
  For Each sourceSheet In sourceWorkbook.Sheets

    ' Find the last row with data in column F
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in column F
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow

      ' Check if the current cell in column F starts with the prefix "Haynes"
      If UCase(Left(sourceSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value, 6)) = "HAYNES" Then

        ' Copy the entire row to the new sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy
        
        ' Paste the copied row to the new sheet
        newSheet.Rows(newSheet.Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

      End If

    Next i

  Next sourceSheet


  ' Get the next file in the folder
  file = Dir()

Loop

' Autofit the columns in the new sheet
newSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

I couldn't touch anything because I didn't know what the problem was. All I could do was hit the compile button.

Comment: `newSheet.Rows.Count` is the number of rows on the sheet, not the number of *occupied* rows.  Use a row counter instead, and increment it by 1 each time you copy a row.

Comment: `newSheet.Rows(newSheet.Rows.Count + 1)` .   This is looking one row down from the bottom of the sheet, which it can't do.  You forgot top add the `.End(xlUp).Row` bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I've altered the code to find the last used row on NewSheet and store this in a new variable called `LastRowNS`. This works the same way as the program finds the last row of the sourceSheet (`LastRow`). I've also moved the declarations (`Dim` statements) outside the loops as they only need to be declared once.

```
Sub CopyRowsWithHaynes()

    ' Create a new workbook to store the copied data
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Create a new sheet in the new workbook
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = newWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    
    ' Set the name of the new sheet
    newSheet.Name = "Haynes Rows"
    
    ' Define the folder to search for Excel files
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Excel Files"
    
    ' Get a list of all Excel files in the folder
    Dim file As String
    file = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xl*")
    
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowNS As Long
    Dim i As Long
        
    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    Do While file <> ""
    
      ' Open the current Excel file
      Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & file)
    
      ' Loop through each sheet in the workbook
      For Each sourceSheet In sourceWorkbook.Sheets
    
        ' Find the last row with data in column F
    
        lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
        ' Loop through each row in column F
    
        For i = 1 To lastRow
    
          ' Check if the current cell in column F starts with the prefix "Haynes"
          If UCase(Left(sourceSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value, 6)) = "HAYNES" Then
    
            ' Copy the entire row to the new sheet
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy
            
            'Find last occupied row on newSheet
            lastRowNS = newSheet.Cells(newSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Paste the copied row to the new sheet
            newSheet.Rows(lastRowNS + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
          End If
    
        Next i
    
      Next sourceSheet
     
      ' Get the next file in the folder
      file = Dir()
    
    Loop
    
    ' Autofit the columns in the new sheet
    newSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```